# What is the best way of duplicating an entire website?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-3.5, code-duplication

I've built a complex site for a client, who wants this duplicated, and re-skinned, so it can be used for other means.

What is the best way of doing this? I'm concerned about copying every file as this means any bugs must be fixed twice, and any improvements must be implmented twice.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by duplicacy? Is the original one is of some other guy? or the client needs some sort of personalizations. If needs personalization like IGoogle or the website that deifferent user can have their own settings and preferences , the look for WebParts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx

Comment: As stated above, I built the existing site, and the client wants it duplicated. I don't understand the relevance of web parts? They just need the whole application duplicated for another purpose. For example, if his existing site is "stackoverflow", hes looking to make a "serverfault" website. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: This is a difficult scenario. But if you have harcoded things for specific puposes in your earlier website then it is not possible that you can reuse it. You have to copy the pages and rebuilt it from scratch. Also it will require a lot of work in backend as well.  I can suggest only the above. But anyhow if you able to create some keys in table that will differentiate the two types then it will work for you. Like if user logins , and in login table there is column that differentiate the SO user and Server Fault user then it will work and you have to place such key in every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look to refactor your code.

Move common functions into a library you can reference from both projects. As you mention that the new site is for a different purpose then you are likely to see divergence and you don't want to hamper yourself later, so extract the common parts and then modify copies (or if appropriate new files) of the remainder to complete your fork.

If you haven't applied good practice already then now is the time to do it and it'll make your work on both sites easier moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Lazarus. To be honest it doesn't sound like I've used the best practice. My code-behind files all contain the code required for the site. For example the /Index.aspx.vb contains the code for logging into the site, binding latest news from the database etc. Have you got any links to good tutorials on how I can move this code into another place so it can be used by both applications?

Comment: Have a look at this http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/07/how-to-write-testable-aspnet-webforms/, I moved onto MVC some time ago so am out of practice with web forms (not sure my brain really clicked to web forms ever) but this article looks like a great intro to writing testable web forms code which will, by default, lead you to more modular and reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

If all the functionality is the same and only the layout is different you could just create a new css file. 2 websites could have exactly the same code base but have different stylesheets and look completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a version control system like subversion or preferably git, is a good way to duplicate your website. You will be able to track the changes that you make and revert to older versions if things do not work out.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement some kind of instantiation, so look and feel, content and data will be shown depending of what instance of the application is accessed.

In other words, each application access to the code with a different application identifier, meaning content will be served depending on it.

Both application identifier will be pointing to different settings, so stylesheet and content will be absolutely isolated, and both domain will be living in the same IIS application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate a whole site it's probably best  to copy the whole thing and amend as necessary. Obviously taking great care not to copy large portions of text or else you may be penalised by the search engines.

There are ways you could put the new site onto the same shared host (say within a subdirectory of the original site) and literally 'share' some files.  If a unique change is required, you could instead reference a 'local' version of a particular file.

However that sounds like a recipe for a headache to me. I'd prefer to duplicate the whole site. It would be much easier to replace one or two functions on separate websites than it would to try and work out *which* website(s) are affected by a particular change to your source.